# How to read the following mathematical notation?

Tags: functions, real-numbers

How to read the following mathematical expression?

> $$\text{For any strictly increasing function } f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R, v(x)=f(u(x))$$

Answer (score 1):

The key bits:

"Strictly increasing function" means that for any $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$.

"$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$": $f$ is a function whose input is a real number, and whose output is a real number.

"$v(x) = f(u(x))$": The transformation $v$, applied to a real number $x$, gives the same result as applying the transformation $u$ to $x$ and then using the transformed value as the input to $f$.

Comment: Sounds correct.

Comment: It would help if there was a bit of context around what u and v are, but what I've written is a translation of as much as the snippet you posted covers.

Comment: u represents a utility function. This is from microeconomics. So, u(x) is utility obtained from consuming good x.

Answer (score 0):

"For any strictly increasing function whose name is $f$ which is a function from the reals to the reals, you have that the result of $v(x)$ is the same as the result of $f(u(x))$"